# Stored procedures and its target tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have three stored procedures lets say A,B and C.
A SP will inserts data in to X table where as B inserts data on to Y table like wise. Now, I need a query to list SP and its target table dynamically.There is no reference/dependancy between table and SP.

Comment: So you want a query that will tell you what table the stored procedure affects?

Answer (score 0):

This is the Query you asked for . You can use Filter by your Procedure Name and Table Name in this Query using `where Clause` .

```
WITH ABC AS (
SELECT 
So.name AS ProcedureName, SOO.Name AS TableName,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by SO.Name,SOO.Name ORDER BY SO.Name,SOO.Name) AS R
FROM sysdepends SD  
INNER JOIN sysobjects SO ON SO.id=Sd.id
INNER JOIN sysobjects SOO ON Soo.id=Sd.depid
WHERE So.Xtype = 'P')
SELECT ProcedureName, TableName FROM ABC
WHERE R = 1
ORDER BY ProcedureName,TableName
```